How to save binary file without schema in Python Avro library?
The FastAvro library has a function for storing serialized data without a schema, which significantly reduces the amount of stored data
https://fastavro.readthedocs.io/en/latest/writer.html#fastavro._write_py.schemaless_writer
Is there such functionality in the Avro Python library?
https://github.com/apache/avro/tree/main
I tried reading the official Avro documentation and also looking for it in the source code. But I didn't find anything similar.
This functionality most likely exists because it is an Avro standard. It just doesn't seem to be described anywhere
